# Querying DBpedia-Live with SPARQL does not give same answer as DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to query DBpedia with [DBpedia Live endpoint](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql).

I have this query :

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?x a dbo:Person .
?x rdfs:label "Usain Bolt"@en .
}
```

This query gives the correct answer with most names I tried (for example `“Teddy Riner"@en`)  but it fails with Usain Bolt and Rachid Badouri.

I don’t get why as their DBpedia pages ([Teddy Riner](http://dbpedia.org/page/Teddy_Riner), [Usain Bolt](http://dbpedia.org/page/Usain_Bolt)) are constructed the same way: they both have a `rdfs:label`, which is written exactly like I did.

It seems to me that there is an incoherence between the endpoint and DBpedia. But I don’t think that it's because the endpoint is not to date.

Even more surprising, this query gives the correct answer:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
?x rdfs:label "Usain Bolt"@en .
}
```

However, Usain Bolt is `a dbo:Person`! Same thing for Rachid Badouri.

Could someone explain me why the first query does not give answer?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: On http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Usain_Bolt, `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Usain_Bolt>` is not `a ` `<http://live.dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>`.

Comment: thanks ! I thought I had to look at dbpedia.org/page/Usain_Bolt. So Usain Bolt is not a Person on live.dbpedia.

Comment: That's clearly a bug in the live extraction framework of DBpedia. There is no type at all besides the YAGO classes - that's weird, No idea which Infobox template has been used for this entity. Looks like [this template] (http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Template:Infobox_sportsperson) has been used, but for other entities based on this template, there is indeed the type `dbo:Athlete` - strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to DBpedia-Live, at the time of writing, [the entity with `rdfs:label "Usain Bolt"@en` has many types](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fx%20a%20%3Ftype%20.%0D%0A%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Usain%20Bolt%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), but is not `a dbo:Person`.  Similar for [the entity with `rdfs:label "Rachid Badouri"@en`](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fx%20a%20%3Ftype%20.%0D%0A%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Rachid%20Badouri%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

In contrast, [the entity with `rdfs:label "Teddy Riner"@en`](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fx%20a%20%3Ftype%20.%0D%0A%3Fx%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Teddy%20Riner%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) *is* `a dbo:Person`.

***Note:*** DBpedia-Live content is a moving target, varying with Wikipedia content changes, adjustments in the templates, and other variables. The statements I made above may no longer be true when you read this.