# How to gracefully handle dbpedia queries of birthDate in different ontologies

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to extract the date of birth of a number of people from dbpedia.org. However some queries fail because the data is in a different attribute. For example:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?birthDate where {
  dbr:Alan_Turing dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

returns [1912-06-23](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3FbirthDate+where+%7B%0D%0A++dbr%3AAlan_Turing+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+) as it should but:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?birthDate where {
  dbr:Grace_Hopper dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

returns an empty [result](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3FbirthDate+where+%7B%0D%0A++dbr%3AGrace_Hopper+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+).

**EDIT TO ADD:**

The original problem was confused by the disparity between the live.dbpedia.org and dbpedia.org, meaning despite the non-live version having dbo:birthDate in both this wasn't the same on live.dbpedia.org. If you compare [Alan Turing](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Alan_Turing) with [Grace Hopper](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Grace_Hopper) you see they have their birthDates in two different ontologies. So the problem is now how to handle those gracefully.

Comment: You are querying on **live**.dbpedia.org. You should use sometging like `dbp:birthDate|dbo:birthDate`. See http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Grace_Hopper.

Comment: @StanislavKralin sorry I don't quite follow - what's the difference between live.dbpedia.org and dbpedia.org? Aren't they sourced from the same data, Wikipedia? I've used a UNION for the two types now but I'm still seeing some failures.

Comment: @StanislavKralin ahh the later failures where rate limiting as I worked through the table. Are you going to put up an answer I can accept or shall I just answer it myself?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345125 and probably many other questions...

Comment: @stsquad Yes, the source is the same, i.e. Wikipedia - but, one is a live version, the other a dump based version. But everything is explained in detail in the link from Stanislav.

Comment: @StanislavKralin: ok I've updated to question. The disparity between the data sources is a distraction to wanting to handle identical data in different ontologies - which is solved by the UNION operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use the UNION operator to find an answer from whichever ontology has it:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?birthDate where {
  { dbr:Alan_Turing dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
  UNION
  { dbr:Alan_Turing dbp:birthDate ?birthDate }
}
```

Gives us [two results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbp%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3FbirthDate+where+%7B%0D%0A++%7B+dbr%3AAlan_Turing+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A++UNION%0D%0A++%7B+dbr%3AAlan_Turing+dbp%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+), both the same. And for Grace Hopper:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?birthDate where {
  { dbr:Grace_Hopper dbo:birthDate ?birthDate }
  UNION
  { dbr:Grace_Hopper dbp:birthDate ?birthDate }
}
```

We only get [one result](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbp%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3FbirthDate+where+%7B%0D%0A++%7B+dbr%3AGrace_Hopper+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A++UNION%0D%0A++%7B+dbr%3AGrace_Hopper+dbp%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+)

As live.dbpedia.org already has a bunch of [namespace prefixes defined](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl) and as suggested by @AKSW we can simplify the call even further. The distinct keyword means identical results from different taxonomies are merged together:

```
select distinct ?birthDate {
  dbr:Grace_Hopper dbo:birthDate|dbp:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

Giving [this result](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FbirthDate+%7B%0D%0A++dbr%3AGrace_Hopper+dbo%3AbirthDate%7Cdbp%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+).

Comment: That's unnecessary verbose...Stanislav already provided the answer `select distinct ?birthDate { dbr:Grace_Hopper dbo:birthDate|dbp:birthDate ?birthDate }`

Comment: @AKSW couldn't get it to work, even with the distinct keyword. I got "Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 6: Undefined namespace prefix in prefix:localpart notation at 'dpb:birthDate' before '?birthDate'". However I'll happily accept another answer that works if it's shorter/more concise than mine. I only added my working code so there an answer to the question and people didn't have to hunt the comments.

Comment: @stsquad, `dbp:`, not `dpb:`! Anyway, `|` should lead to performance degradation on DBpedia, esp. with more than one "starting point" (e. g. `SELECT * WHERE {
VALUES (?s) {(dbr:Alan_Turing) (dbr:Grace_Hopper)}
?s dbp:birthDate|dbo:birthDate ?birthDate 
}`)

Comment: @stsquad If you just would have copied my query it you wouldn't have seen this  error...

Comment: @StanislavKralin hmm was [something missing](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+*+WHERE+%7B+VALUES+%28%3Fs%29+%7B%28dbr%3AAlan_Turing%29+%28dbr%3AGrace_Hopper%29%7D+%3Fs+dbp%3AbirthDate%7Cdbo%3AbirthDate+%3FbirthDate+%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+)?

Comment: By the way the reason I'm only looking up one name at a time is because the SPARQL fragment is being called for [each entry in table in org-mode](https://gist.github.com/stsquad/665542a64e99b71a4ef128aad4f00ab1#looking-up-birth-dates).

Comment: *"something missing"* — that's what I said, increase timeout :).

Comment: @StanislavKralin ahh ok - so what is the prefered form given we are only querying one resource at a time? This is why I was expecting someone else to answer the question for the points/karma ;-)

Comment: @stsquad, I think UNION` is more efficient on DBpedia. BTW, you could also try Wikidata .